# SQL Server Table Relationship returning multiple values, require only 1

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on a project to build tables for an application. We receive orders with an attribute shown below.

table1:

| order_id | feature |
| --- | --- |
| order1 | feature1;feature2;feature3 |
| order2 | feature2;feature3;feature4 |
| order3 | feature1 |
| order4 | feature4;feature3;feature1 |

Some of these features are related to a specific process so my goal is to try to map features to a specific name. I have the below table that I'm trying to map it with

table2:

| feature_id | feature_1 | feature_2 | feature_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aFeature | feature1 | null | null |
| bFeature | feature2 | null | null |
| aFeature | feature1 | feature3 | null |
| aFeature | feature1 | feature2 | feature3 |

My thinking on the second table design is to check if all 3 columns are within the feature from table1 then return feature_id, if not then check if 2 columns match etc down to 1 match or zero matches.

This is my SQL statement I have been testing,

```
SELECT
      order_id,
      feature,
      fm.feature_id
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 AS fm on 
(
fm.feature_1 is not null AND fm.feature_2 is not null AND fm.feature_3 is not null AND
feature like CONCAT('%', fm.feature_1, '%') AND
feature like CONCAT('%', fm.feature_2, '%') AND
feature like CONCAT('%', fm.feature_3, '%')
)
OR
(
fm.feature_1 is not null AND fm.feature_2 is not null AND 
fm.feature_3 is null AND feature like CONCAT('%', fm.feature_1, '%') AND
feature like CONCAT('%', fm.feature_2, '%')
)
OR
(
fm.feature_1 is not null AND fm.feature_2 is null AND 
fm.feature_3 is null AND
feature like CONCAT('%', fm.feature_1, '%')
)
```

Any suggestions on how to rebuild or make my statement not return multiple rows would be appreciated. Any help would be awesome!!

Comment: Is feature1;feature2 the same thing as feature2;feature1 ?

Comment: Yes, these are the same thing. feature1;feature2 could be out of order which would result in feature2;feature1 but they should map to the same feature_id.

Comment: This violates the most basic SQL design rule - one field, one value. If you want to relate options to features create an `OptionFeatures` table with an `OptionID` and `FeatureID` column. It takes a lot less space, it's a lot easier to query and can take advantage of indexing to speed up queries.

Comment: Hello Panagiotis, thanks for replying. I understand table1 with multiple features in feature column doesn't validate 1st nominal form. This is how the system we use has the data and sends us the data. Do you have an example of what could be done to make this easier?

Comment: Still hoping for someone to help me out with these tables...still struggling a bit to understand how to build this to get it to work.